# PyQt QThread Segfault while streaming a video

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

I am trying to develop an application in pyqt to use a Dalsa camera to capture images and manipulate them.

The first point I am having trouble with is the camera stream on the gui.

Following the tutorial https://gist.github.com/docPhil99/ca4da12c9d6f29b9cea137b617c7b8b1 (which works well with my webcam) I modified it to make it compatible with my needs.

I am experiencing the problem that the moment the program starts, the gui refreshes 5-6 frames and then crashes randomly when it runs the `self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(img)` function to update the image getting a segmentation error.

I can't figure out if the problem is upstream with the camera libraries(Which I don't think so since if I don't send the signal to the gui the camera processes the images in the thread) or if I am doing operations that are not good for pyqt workflow.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QWidget, QLabel, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, Qt, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QObject
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

from frontend.gui import Ui_MainWindow
import numpy as np
import sys
import pygigev
import faulthandler


class VideoThread(QThread):

    change_pixmap_signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._run_flag = True
        self.ctx = pygigev.PyGigEV()
        self.ctx.GevOpenCamera()
        self.params = self.ctx.GevGetImageParameters()
        self.widthFrame = self.params['width'] #1456
        self.heightFrame = self.params['height'] #1088
        x_offset = int(self.widthFrame / 2)
        y_offset = int(self.heightFrame / 2)
        self.ctx.GevSetImageParameters(self.widthFrame, self.heightFrame, x_offset, y_offset, self.params['pixelFormat'][0])

    def run(self):
        self.ctx.GevInitializeImageTransfer(10)
        self.ctx.GevStartImageTransfer(-1)
        self.params = self.ctx.GevGetCameraInterfaceOptions()
        while self._run_flag:
            img = self.ctx.GevWaitForNextImage(1)
            if type(img) is int:
                if img == -6:
                    continue
                else:
                    break

            img = img.reshape(self.heightFrame, self.widthFrame)
            self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(img) # < --- Here the crash, if i detach the stream works, but not visible on the pyqt gui

        # shut down capture system
        self.ctx.GevStopImageTransfer()
        self.ctx.GevAbortImageTransfer()
        self.ctx.GevCloseCamera()

    def stop(self):
        """Sets run flag to False and waits for thread to finish"""
        self._run_flag = False
        self.wait()

class Window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow,QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.imageStream)

        # create the video capture thread
        self.streamThread = VideoThread()
        # connect its signal to the update_image slot
        self.streamThread.change_pixmap_signal.connect(self.update_image)
        # start the thread
        self.streamThread.start()


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.streamThread.stop()
        event.accept()

    @pyqtSlot(np.ndarray)
    def update_image(self, img):
        h, w = img.shape
        bytes_per_line = 2 * w
        convert_to_Qt_format = QtGui.QImage(img, w, h, bytes_per_line, QtGui.QImage.Format_Grayscale8)
        p = convert_to_Qt_format.scaled(self.imageStream.width(), self.imageStream.height(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio) #width 728, height 544
        p = QPixmap.fromImage(p)
        self.imageStream.setPixmap(p)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Displayed errors

```
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Thread 0x00007efceee35640 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/---/main.py", line 50 in run  #  img = self.ctx.GevWaitForNextImage(1)

Thread 0x00007efd769f3440 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/---/main.py", line 103 in update_image  #  p = QPixmap.fromImage(p)
  File "/home/---/main.py", line 113 in <module>  #  sys.exit(app.exec())

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't safely send an ndarray via a signal without keeping a reference to it. PyQt will just send a pointer, rather than attempting to serialise the underlying data. The way your code is written, the `img` variable will be immediately overwritten by the next iteration of the while-loop. So when you try to create a QImage in the slot, Qt will attempt to access memory that no longer exists, resulting in a crash. The signal should send a copy of the image data (i.e. as bytes), rather than a pointer to an ndarray.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Basically you recommend that I change the type of signal that is sent so that it sends me the whole packet and not a pointer to an ndarray?
Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach, I've tried putting pyqtSignal of type bytes, taking the image in the thread in ndarray format and turning it into bytes, and then turning it back into type ndarray in the update_image function when the packet was sent. I still get the same segfault error, am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you converting it back to an ndarray? You can just create the image directly from the bytes. In fact, it is safe to create the QImage from a copy of the data within the thread, and then emit that image.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem thanks to your advice, thank you very much.
I have edited the topic with the solution.

Comment: Your solution is not thread safe. You should emit the QImage, and create the pixmap in the main thread. Qt does not support GUI operations of any kind outside the main thread (which includes pixmaps). Your current solution may seem to work at the moment, but sooner or later you will very likely encounter problems. (PS: please don't add solutions by editing your question. Instead, you should post an answer and accept it.)

Comment: All right,I fixed the code and everything seems to be working.I will do some testing. Thanks for your patience